# How to run 'ionic serve' in global WEB?

Tags: ip, port, ionic-framework, cloud9-ide

I'm new in Ionic Framework, so I need your help. When I'm running `ionic serve` on localhost everything is great. But now I'm trying to work with [Cloud9](http://c9.io), it prints:

```
The port 8100 was taken on the host 172.17.12.3 - using port 8101 instead
The port 35729 was taken on the host 172.17.12.3 - using port 35730 instead
Running live reload server: http://172.17.12.3:35730
Watching : [ 'www/**/*', '!www/lib/**/*' ]
Running dev server: http://172.17.12.3:8101
```

But this adresses don't work at all. And i get an error from Cloud9:

```
Error: you may be using the wrong PORT & IP for your server app. Try passing $PORT and $IP to properly launch your application.
```

So how can I set $PORT and $IP in Ionic?

Answer (score 3):

Since Cloud9 forwards port 8080 (which is the value of $PORT), you need to tell ionic to use that instead. With the recent change of allowing multiple ports, port 8081 and 8082 are also allowed, so you need to tell ionic to use 8081 (or 8082) as the livereload ports. The command that *should* work is:

```
ionic serve -p 8080 -l 8081
```

I also think that adding `-a` would help since with that option it *appears* to bind to IP 0.0.0.0 which you should be binding to in the first place. For more information about Ionic cli options, please check out [the Ionic CLI github page](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli)

Answer (score 0):

simple solution is to close the terminal in which you are running the serve request and open new terminal then give ionic serve request it will take the 8100 port (which you gave in your code)